# Como puedo emplear ng-repeat y solo mostrar la primera opción

Tags: angularjs

Quisiera saber como utilizar un ng-repeat pero solo quiero mostrar la primera opción, las demás opciones van a depender de un botón!

Este es el código: http://plnkr.co/edit/oxtojjEPwkKng9iKkc14?p=preview

Quiero que se visualice la primera opción, el primer select y el input numérico, y los demás se van a visualizar al darle click al botón, el botón va a aparecer hasta que ya no haya más opciones que seleccionar.

En este caso si selecciona una opción y un puntaje se guarda en el array, y si quiere seleccionar más opciones le da click al botón para agregar otra opción.

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: En el plunker veo que usas selectize pero no veo que uses `ng-repeat`. Estás intentando llenar los datos del selectize sólo con la primera opción? Si no es así donde es que usas el `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más fácil es usando el filtro [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo#!)

> Crea un nuevo array o cadena de caracteres conteniendo sólo el número especificado de elementos. Los elementos son tomados de tanto del principio como el final del arreglo, cadena o número inicial, según esté especificado por el valor y signo (positivo or negativo) del límite. Si el valor entrado es un número es convertido primero a una cadena.

Luego haces algo como

```
<div ng-repeat="opt in myOptions | limitTo : 1">
 {{opt.text}}
</div>
```

Este método tiene las siguientes ventajas:

- Las operaciones se hacen en memoria y antes de procesar el `ng-repeat` lo cual es mucho más eficiente que manipular tus datos con otras directivas
- Si cambias de idea y quieres mostrar más valores solo tienes que cambiar un valor y listo.
- Los parámetros de `limitTo` se evalúan como cualquier expresión de angular y se pueden controlar con variables

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cantidad = 1;
    $scope.opciones = [{
      value: '1',
      text: 'opcion 1'
    }, {
      value: '2',
      text: 'opcion 2'
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="opt in opciones | limitTo : cantidad">
    {{opt.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas añadir un `track by $index` a la iteración de tu ng-repeat, de modo que luego ocultes aquellos cuyo índice no corresponda a la primera entrada; algo del tipo: `ng-show='$index == 1 && not_clicked_button'`.

[ngRepeat en AngularDocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no necesitas el track by, ya que puedes usar el $first que es un boolean que te indica si es el primero.

```
<h2 ng-if="$first">First Option</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola como puedo hacer para mostrar todo ordenador pero mostrar un contenido el primero ejemplo:
D

A

B

C

F

G

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, tienes que realizar tu propia pregunta para que sea visible a otros desarrolladores, la pregunta debe ser basada en [ask]. No olvides realizar el [tour], saludos!